# Delete multiple patterns using sed

Tags: sed

I have data in below format

```
SQL> BEGIN Oracle Query; END;
SQL> 123                              : TEST ABC
345                           : Yes
-----------------
123                           : TEST BDE
345                           : Yes
-----------------
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
```

I want to get data into below format :--

```
123                           : TEST ABC
345                           : Yes
123                           : TEST BDE
345                           : Yes
```

I am able to delete the records in in multiple sed commands like to delete everything before 1st 123 I use `sed  '/123/,$!d' oracle.txt`
and then delete all SQL> term and then delete rows from PL/SQL.

Is there anyway to do it in single statement , also I dont want to hardcode 123 in the sed but SQL> as 123 may change to any other value.

Basically if I can get data only between SQL> an PL/SQL in a single command   that would suffice

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, this one-liner gives you desired output:

```
sed 's/^SQL> //;/^[0-9]/!d' file
```

#### update

```
tac file|awk '/^PL\/SQL/,/^SQL> /{sub(/^SQL> /,"");if(!/PL\/SQL/ && !/^-*$/) print}'|tac
```

Comment: Hi Kent... Here again that dependency is on number , if 1st row is axs instead of 123 it will not work.

Comment: Hi Ken.. This works great .. I have only more doubt on similar lines but bit different.  Suppose i have data between { ABC : 123 , BCD : 234} , {EFG : 456 , GHI : 789 } .. Can same logic be used to  do so ?

Comment: @user2854333 you can do a test. also try to understand the code and extend it for your new requirements. Or post it as a  new question if you cannot solve it.